# Rotate canvas in Adobe Animate CC

Tags: animate-cc

We've made an animated ad banner using Adobe Animate CC (using actionscript 10.3).

The ad agency needs us to rotate the whole thing 90 deg counter-clockwise before submitting to make it work on their platform.

Any idea how to rotate the canvas including all the animating elements?

We've thought about resizing the canvas then rotating each layer individually. However, this messes up the layout as each layer rotates around its own axis and not the canvas itself.

Is there an easier way to do this (possibly even a third party tool?)

Answer (score 0):

One way that you can approach this problem is to copy your animation layers into one MovieClip. This will essentially group all your animations together so you can rotate the MovieClip as one object as opposed to rotating every animation individually.

If you go with this approach, you may have to update the size of your canvas to match the size of your newly rotated MovieClip.